# they are a nation destitute of counsel

Tags: deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 32:28 (NASB)

> For they are a nation destitute of counsel,
>
> And there is no understanding in them.

Is the word "they" referring to the israelites, their opponents or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deut 32 contains the famous "Song of Moses" which is referenced in other places such as Rev 15.  We should delay ourselves by considering the full analysis of the important passage.  Suffice to say here that V15-33 contains a future prediction/prophecy of Israel's apostasy, its causes and its cure.

In V28, we have a section dealing with Israel's fall from Jehovah's favor and the what happens when Israel became a second-class nation:

> For they are a nation destitute of counsel, And there is no
> understanding in them. [NASB]

The reason for this is stated in the surrounding verses but is made more explicit in several other places -

- Prov 1:7 - The fear of the LORD is the beginning of knowledge, but fools despise wisdom and instruction.
- Prov 9:10 - The fear of the LORD is the beginning of wisdom, and knowledge of the Holy One is understanding.
- Ps 111:10 - The fear of the LORD is the beginning of wisdom; all who follow his precepts have good understanding. To him belongs eternal praise.
- Ps 19:9 - The fear of the LORD is pure, enduring forever. The decrees of the LORD are firm, and all of them are righteous.

Thus, when Israel turned away from God, their politics and government became corrupt and their prosperity declined.

Comment: So you'd say the Israelites?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - YES